# Recently viewed product not working properly in home page

Tags: magento-1.9

I added recently viewed product block in home page it's fetching properly recent view product if i used same code in some other page it working fine. I don't know what is the problem can you please suggest

```
<?php if ($_products = $this->getRecentlyViewedProducts()): ?>
<div class="block block-list block-viewed">
    <div class="tittle_block">
<div class="tittle">Recently Viewed Product</div>
</div>
    <div class="block-content slideshow-container"> <!-- Added a class for parent container-->
        <ol id="recently-viewed-items"> <!-- Added a class for container-->
        <?php foreach ($_products as $_item): ?>
            <li class="item">
                <a href="<?php echo $this->getProductUrl($_item) ?>">
                    <span class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_item, 'thumbnail')->resize(185, 185)->setWatermarkSize('30x10'); ?>" width="185" height="185" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getProductName()) ?>" /></span>
                </a>
                <div class="product-details">
                    <p class="product-name">
                        <a href="<?php echo $this->getProductUrl($_item) ?>">
                            <?php echo $this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($_item, $_item->getName() , 'name') ?>
                        </a>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_item, true, '-new') ?>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ol>
        <script type="text/javascript">decorateList('recently-viewed-items');</script>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

[image]

Comment: Your code pls??

Comment: Please add your codes, what you've already done!

Comment: check my updated question

Comment: @Manojkothari where did you add this code ?

Comment: I added in my theme /template/reports/product_viewed.phtml. After that i call in this way {{block type="core/template" template="reports/product_viewed.phtml"}}

Comment: Could you be more clear as to what is 'not working'. The recently viewed products is pulled from the session object as a user moves through the site. One of the reasons you don't find this on a home page (it's almost always in the sidebar of a category page or product page) is because the user hasn't viewed any products yet, and so there is nothing to display. And since most users never return back to the homepage after they begin looking though the site, the functionality isn't often viewed there. So there is a good chance that the user session is empty when you are looking at the homepage.

Answer (score 1):

You have to call the recently viewed product in cms with block type 
**reports/product_viewed**

i.e.,

```
{{block type="reports/product_viewed" template="reports/product_viewed.phtml"}}
```

Comment: This is working for inner page but not working for home page

Comment: @Manojkothari Replace this code with yours and check its working or not.

Comment: Please check Home page not featch http://totaltoys.com/ but http://totaltoys.com/update featch properly

Comment: show your cms content

Comment: check my updated question